# How can I set cron every last monday on aws cloudwatch events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to set cron to my lambda function.
I wish that fired 10:00 am on the last monday of every month.

```
cron(* * * * [something special words here] *)

I wish next fire schedule will like this.

2020-04-27 10:00:00 JST
2020-05-25 10:00:00 JST
2020-06-29 10:00:00 JST
2020-07-27 10:00:00 JST
2020-08-31 10:00:00 JST
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Check here. The link (from serverfault) reports your situation: https://serverfault.com/questions/265879/cron-job-that-runs-on-the-last-monday-of-the-month

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloudwatch's schedule expressions have a built-in wildcard for `L`ast days.

The expression would be,

```
cron(0 10 ? * 2L *)
```

The `L` wildcard in the day-of-week field specifies the last day of the month. Here `2L` means the last monday of the month, where `1-7` represent `SUN-SAT`.

Comment: That's not as expected. In the field of "day of the week" we define "last day of the month"!